# How can you globally set sqlalchemy_session_persistence for factory boy in only one place?

Tags: python, factory-boy

Without adding `MyFlushingModelFactory` as the base class of all my Factory classes, how can I set the Meta class value of `sqlalchemy_session_persistence`

I'm running pytest and when the machine is under heavy load, some of my tests are failing with Integrity errors.  Most of these issues can be cleared up by simply adding flushes to the code around factory model creation.  But I don't want to go adding this to all of my factory classes.  Is there some way to set the Meta class value once and have it affect all my Factories without the extra work?

```
# encoding: utf-8
import factory

class MyFlushingModelFactory(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        sqlalchemy_session_persistence = factory.alchemy.SESSION_PERSISTENCE_FLUSH
```

I'm wanting to set the default behavior of the `SQLAlchemyModelFactory` to flush the created object to disk as part of the `.create` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For us a base class with overridden options seems to work:

```
from factory.alchemy import SQLAlchemyModelFactory

class BaseSQLAlchemyModelFactory(SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    """Always inherit from here"""

    class Meta:
        abstract = True  # Cannot initialize
        sqlalchemy_session = db.session  # The session object. In our case, this is the flask-sqlalchemy `db` object
        sqlalchemy_session_persistence = 'flush'


class WorkflowFactory(BaseSQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    """Subclass that actually is the factory"""

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Comment: That's what I had to do too, was hoping there was something less intrusive in a large code base....

Comment: So i'd not comment on code conventions and structure, but this should be just one place you subclass and inherit from, right? From what i understand, a lot of projects in web frameworks do this. Sentry, for example, has a bunch of custom classes.

Comment: Yes, but if you already have a couple hundred fixtures in a project you inherited, that's a lot of changes to make, whereas setting this on the existing class would be a one change kind of thing.

Comment: Then maybe some metaclass magic can help here? But you'll have to be careful to override the `SQLAlchemyModelFactory` metaclass i.e follow `base.Factory` which it subclasses. This will lead to changes in how the attributes are instrumented in the class by the metaclass. I'd stay a bit away from that  path in production code :/